# NodeJs MongoDB Nested Queries - Run Callback Synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

I have a code block like below. I could not find how to achieve that.
- I have rooms collection in mongodb and documents in this collection include user id array. Each room can have multiple users.
- So I want to find that usernames which are in the rooms that include my user Id.

DB collections:
Rooms {roomId:1, users:[99, 100]}, {roomId:2, users:[99, 101]}
Users {_id:99, name:"Alex"},{_id:100, name:"Harry"},{_id:101, name:"Tom"}

```
var userId = 99;
var arrUserIds = [];
var arrRooms = [];
var strUserNames = "";
db.collection("rooms").find({"users.userId":userId}).toArray(function(err, rooms) {

    for (var i=0; i<rooms.length; i++) {
        arrUserIds = [];

        for(var j=0; j<rooms[i].users.length; j++){
            arrUserIds.push(new BSON.ObjectID(rooms[i].users[j].userId));   
        }

        db.collection('users').find({"_id": {$in: arrUserIds}}).toArray(function(err, users) {
            strUserNames = users.map(function(elem){return elem.name;}).join(", ");
            arrRooms.push({_id:rooms[i].roomId, name:strUserNames });
        });

    }

    res.json({rooms:arrRooms});
});
```

I want to have a result like that: 
arrRooms: [ { _id:1:, name:"Alex, Harry" }, { _id:2:, name:"Alex, Tom" } ]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning res.json before the second .find callback executes, so it will be empty. You need to restructure to wait for all the async callbacks before responding, like so:

```
var userId = 99;
var arrRooms = [];
var strUserNames = "";

db.collection("rooms").find({"users.userId":userId}).toArray(function(err, rooms) {

    var completed = 0;
    var complete = function() {
        completed++;
        if (completed === rooms.length - 1) {
            res.json({rooms:arrRooms});
        }
    }


    for (var i=0; i<rooms.length; i++) {
        var arrUserIds = [];
        var roomId = rooms[i].roomId;

        for(var j=0; j<rooms[i].users.length; j++){
            arrUserIds.push(new BSON.ObjectID(rooms[i].users[j].userId));   
        }

        db.collection('users').find({"_id": {$in: arrUserIds}}).toArray(function(err, users) {
            strUserNames = users.map(function(elem){return elem.name;}).join(", ");
            arrRooms.push({_id:roomId, name:strUserNames });

            complete();
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: I want to have a result like that:
arrRooms: [{_id:1:, name:"Alex, Harry" },{_id:2:, name:"Alex, Tom" }]

But your answer does not give me this result.
I need to run second .find callback synchronously.

Comment: Ah, I see - I'll have another go.

Comment: @barisusanmaz Updated - does that cover it?

Comment: No, I am sorry it does not work. That gives me only last room information in  3 rooms.

Comment: @barisusanmaz one last try, I've just updated the answer; resetting the arrUserIds array inside the for loop.

Comment: I had tried it but does not work. I want to share my refinements.
rooms[i].roomId  did not work in the second .find callback and gave me error. So I set its value before second .find callback into a variable   "roomId = rooms[i].roomId;".   I noticed that before the second .find started, the first .find had finished so "roomId" variable always gave me the last room id but names are true. 

It gives me result like this:
roomId: 1, users:[alex, tom]
roomId:1, users:[alex, harry]

Comment: @barisusanmaz try with `var roomId = rooms[i].roomId` - the `var` is vital else you'll be setting roomId on the global scope which will be accessible on the next loop around, whereas with var it becomes locally scoped and will be a "different" variable each time around the loop. I've updated the answer to reflect this.